# IllegalArgumentException: Expected 2 paths, but got 3? What does paths mean in this exception?

Tags: java, querydsl

I am trying to implement a sql query using queryDSL framework. I am getting the following error only when I try to end the query by adding the "list" clause and trying to return some values.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 2 paths, but got 3

If I skip the "list" clause and in-turn convert the query in SQLSubQuery, then the generated query looks fine.

I am unable to understand what "paths" mean and how to look for the exact problem?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what your query looks like?

Comment: also please provide the full stacktrace